# Excel pivot table grouping overlaps

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pivot table with salaries as rows and I'm trying to group them neatly together. However, when I try to group by increments of 5000 I get ranges like 0-5000, 5000-10000, and so on. This is clearly incorrect (groups overlap and 5001 entries per group).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine for me. What version of Excel are you using?

[image: Excel 2013]